# How/where to host a Java server on the cloud?

Tags: java, android, web-services

I created a simple Android app and a Java server to go along with it. How and where can I host that server so that it's running on my machine at home?

I'm a newbie so hopefully my question makes sense.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are lots of free hosting sites are available(some sites are not free):
**Openshift** is one of the free site.

i) https://www.openshift.com/web-hosting/java?sc_cid=70160000000UJC4AAO&gclid=CI6Lpu7X6r0CFckWMgodHEIAug
ii) http://www.rackspace.com/
iii) http://www.whoishostingthis.com/compare/java/#.

Comment: Thank you for those. Are you familiar with Openshift? Can I simply upload my Java file or is more involved?

Comment: Just register https://www.openshift.com/app/account/new?then=%2Fapp%2Faccount%2Fplans%2Fbronze%2Fupgrade . Instruction will be there for your help sir.